# Logistic regression output using scikit-learn python not matching

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Trying to execute the following code to predict Values using Logistic Regression but I am not getting proper results even hen the same exact row that is present in the training data is present in the test data.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd


X_train_data = {'NegativeScore': [0.25,0.00,0.00,0.00], \
             'NeutralScore':[0.00,0.12,0.00,0.00], \
             'PositiveScore': [0.00,0.00,0.19,0.43]}

X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train_data, columns = \
            ['NegativeScore', 'NeutralScore', 'PositiveScore'])

y_train_data = {'Y': ["Negative", "Others", "Others", "Others"]}
y_train = pd.DataFrame(y_train_data, columns = ['Y'])
y_train = y_train.values.ravel()

X_test_data = {'NegativeScore': [0.25, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00], \
               'NeutralScore':  [0.00, 0.28, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00], \
               'PositiveScore': [0.00, 0.00, 0.20, 0.30, 0.11]}
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test_data, columns = ['NegativeScore', 'NeutralScore', 'PositiveScore'])

y_test_data = {'Y': ["Negative", "Others", "Others", "Others", "Others"]}
y_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test_data, columns = ['Y'])
y_test = y_test.values.ravel()

logreg = LogisticRegression()
# train the model using X_train_dtm
print("X_train")
print(X_train)
print("y_train")
print(y_train)

print("X_test")
print(X_test)

logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make class predictions for X_test_dtm
y_pred_class = logreg.predict(X_test)
print("y_pred_class")
print(y_pred_class)
```

The code output is as follows:

```
X_train
   NegativeScore  NeutralScore  PositiveScore
0           0.25          0.00           0.00
1           0.00          0.12           0.00
2           0.00          0.00           0.19
3           0.00          0.00           0.43
y_train
['Negative' 'Others' 'Others' 'Others']
X_test
   NegativeScore  NeutralScore  PositiveScore
0           0.25          0.00           0.00
1           0.00          0.28           0.00
2           0.00          0.00           0.20
3           0.00          0.00           0.30
4           0.00          0.00           0.11
y_pred_class
['Others' 'Others' 'Others' 'Others' 'Others']
```

The first value in y_pred_class should have given "Negative".

- Whys is it not able to predict the Negative record accurately?
- Should I be using some other model in this scenario to get the
  correct results?

Comment: was not able to understand why this question got a -1? What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some more training cases with 'negative' labels. Logistic regression  cannot logically infer from one training case (it does not learn like a child), it needs more training instances, the more the better. 
You could add training cases step by step and each time use logreg.predict_proba(X_test) to see how probabilities change. It is probably sufficient to add two or three more cases, and your model will work fine.